# Is it possible to an SNS Topic indefinitely?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm interested in publishing SES analytics data to SNS and publishing the SNS topic to somewhere (S3?) to store the data permanently.

Our control flow is as follows:

1. Create SES config set
2. Create SNS topic
3. Set config set destination to SNS topic
4. publish topic to s3?

[The SNS subscribe() function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#subscribe-property) says after confirming the subscription, it will last for 3 days. I'd like to make it last indefinitely so we can gather email analytics longer than 3 days.

**If this is a reasonable approach**, how would someone remove that expiration?

**If this is the wrong approach**, how should I approach storing SES analytics data permanently?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your purpose to store emails received to SES to S3 or send and receive both?

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting the documentation.  You have only a limited amount of time during which you can *initially confirm* the subscription, otherwise the token expires and can no longer be used... but this is a one-time operation.  Once confirmed, the subscription itself is indefinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through SNS is too much round trip.

SES (Events) --> Firehose --> (S3 / Redshift / Elastisearch)

You can configure SES to send analytics data to Kinesis Firehose. You can configure Kinesis Firehose to deliver to S3 or Redshift or Elastisearch, depending upon your needs.

**SES Events to Firehose:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-firehose-contents.html

**Event Data Transformation with Lambda:**

With an intermediate Data transformation with Lambda you can manipulate the data before sending it to the desired destination.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I really like this solution instead of SNS. Thank you!

Comment: Quick followup: Is S3 a good choice for analyzing the email data? I saw there's charges for PUT/GET requests. I'm interested in having users be able to access a web app containing this data.

Comment: You can store it in S3 and analyze with Athena. If you want performance you need to use Redshift. Also you can gzip and store with firehose, that can reduce the amount of PUT and GET you make.